# jQuery colorbox strangely fails

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to open an iframe with the colorbox plugin in the window.onload event. I'm almost having success, but something strange started happening. Let-me show the example above works properly:

```
        <script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", closeButton:false, escKey: false, overlayClose: false, opacity:0.30});
            });
            window.onload=function(){
                $(".iframe").colorbox({href:"http://www.website.com/", open: true});
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a class='iframe' href="http://wikipedia.com"></a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that on the body I have:

> < p>< a class='iframe' href="http://wikipedia.com">< /a>< /p>

If I remove this line, the iframe doesn't open anymore. I'm newbie to jquery, so for me this is no sense. And I don't want to work with 'no sense' stuff. Could you guys explain me better how to make it work in the correct way?

Comment: Please search about Jquery selectors... You will understand that the colorbox is attached on the element with class `iframe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work when you remove the code from the DOM is that because you tell colorbox to search the DOM for an element with the class ".iframe" and then assign itself to that element.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.colorbox({href:"http://wikipedia.com", iframe:true});
}
```

Comment: Uhmm... It's not working, and the chrome console says: _Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://wikipedia.com _ at jquery.min.js
_EDIT:_ I did: `$.colorbox({href:"http://wikipedia.com", iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", closeButton:false, escKey: false, overlayClose: false, opacity:0.30});` and it worked... Is that ok?